# Connecting two STM32f4discovery boards

Tags: usb, serial, communication

We have two STM32F4Discovery boards with Micro USB's for serial communication.
Is it possible to connect two boards to allow communication between them?

Is there is any different hardware other than the cable that would be required?

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am remembering wrong, the STM32F4 variant on that board does have a USB OTG host interface which could be either a host or device.  In theory it would be possible to make one board a USB host and the other a device and place them in communication, however this would have a fairly high software complexity, and would require an OTG adapter cable.

A much simpler solution would be to utilize a logic-level serial (UART) interface, several of which are present on each board.  This will be orders of magnitude simpler to support in software.  All you will need is to establish a common ground, then connect the transmit pin of each board to the receive pin of the other.  For short cabling runs you may be able to to operate at a baud rate approaching a megabit per second, possibly more.

There are additional interfaces which could be utilized - SPI, I2C, possibly ethernet (with external support parts), etc, but logic level serial will be by far the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Chris mentions in system USB OTG capability - which is effectively running a subset of USB host mode on what would usually be a slave device.
If you do not have this capability you can buy stand alone converters which connect USB slave to USB slave and which use OTG mode to allow the bidirectional USB interface. OTG interface IC's are usually made to work with a microcontroller to give it USB host capability, but standalone OTG bridge ICs **may** exist.

[Here are many examples of OTG interfaces](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=otg+bridge&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2-JxUfz-F4adiAeazoCwDw&ved=0CD4QsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1081#hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=otg+bridge+USB&oq=otg+bridge+USB&gs_l=img.3...22708.24135.0.24582.4.4.0.0.0.0.214.709.1j0j3.4.0...0.0...1c.1.9.img.cCJJg7DZwv8&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.aGc&fp=4f5c2738245ebf40&biw=1920&bih=1081) allowing USB-USN interconnection. Where circuits are shown they seem to invariably use multiple ICs' - usually a processor + OTG interface proper.

Typical USB OTG interface IC. TI TUSB6010BZQE, TUSB6010BIZQE
[USB2.0 High Speed (HS) On-the-Go (OTG) Dual Role Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb6010b.pdf)